# Connecting to remote JMS Provider

Tags: jms, websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to connect to a foreign JMS provider from Websphere Application Server.
Can we connect to a remote JMS provider from Websphere Application Server without using Websphere MQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need WebSphere MQ, if your provider supports JMS 1.1 you can configure it as Generic JMS Provider. See the following page as a startnig point: [Choosing a messaging provider](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tm_ep.html?lang=en)

> - Choose a third-party messaging provider. You can use any third-party
>     messaging provider that supports the JMS Version 1.1 unified
>     connection factory. You might want to do this, for example, because of
>     existing investments.
>
> Notes:
>   To administer a third-party messaging provider, use the resource adaptor or client supplied by the third party. You can still use the
>   WebSphere Application Server administrative console to administer the
>   JMS connection factories and destinations that are within WebSphere
>   Application Server, but you cannot use the administrative console to
>   administer the JMS provider itself, or any of its resources that are
>   outside of WebSphere Application Server.
>    To use message-driven beans (MDBs), third-party messaging providers must include Application Server Facility (ASF), an optional feature that is part of the JMS Version 1.1 specification, or use an inbound resource adapter that conforms to the Java EE Connector Architecture (JCA) Version 1.5 or 1.6 specification.